# How to sync an Outlook email folder to a Onedrive folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, onedrive

Is it possible to synchronize a Onedrive folder with an Outlook email folder on a Windows 10 PC? If so, how to set this up? If not, I would greatly appreciate suggestions on how to make an Outlook email folder available to others (with permission) to view.

Comment: No; That’s what a group email is for.

Answer (score 0):

To make an Outlook email folder available to others with permission to view, you can follow these steps:

1. Open Outlook and navigate to the folder you want to share.
2. Right-click on the folder and select Permissions.
3. In the Permissions window, click on **Add** to add the email addresses of the people you want to share the folder with.
4. Select the appropriate permission level for each person from the Permission Level drop-down menu.
5. Click OK to save the changes.

Once you have shared the folder, the people you shared it with will be able to view it in their Outlook account.
You can also refer to: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/i-want-to-share-an-outlook-folder-with-another/d01bb582-8351-46b1-9eb7-bd9ab169bed1

Comment: Faery, thank you for  your help! I think I have correctly permitted the folder to the recipient, and per the link you gave, I also permitted my Inbox since it is a subfolder of the Inbox that I wish to share. But the recipient doesn't see it, and the instruction in the link to click Folders > Add Shared Folder didn't work for her because she doesn't see Folders tab to click on in her Outlook. Please advise if you can, and thanks again.

Comment: Aha ... on her Outlook it is File > Open & Export > Add shared folder > Name . She chose my address. But still can't find my folder in her menu.

Comment: If you want to share sub-folders, please refer to : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/797858/share-folder

Answer (score 0):

The entire account has to be permitted to the recipient first, with no read access. Then permit the inbox, no read access. Then permit the subfolder, WITH read access.